# .vimrc does not appear when I 'ls', but I can open it when it type 'vim .vimrc' in same directory. why?

Tags: command-line, ls

I was searching for my vimrc so I could change my settings in vim, but was struggling to find it. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977649/how-to-locate-the-vimrc-file-used-by-vim-editor) which gave me the directory of the vimrc (`user/home/.vimrc`) that my vim is currently using, but when I went into `home` and hit `ls` to find the file, there was nothing that said `.vimrc` or `vimrc`. However, when I typed `vim .vimrc` in that same directory, I was able to open the file.

I am very new to everything Linux, so I don't know what exactly I am getting wrong; does `ls` not list all the files in a directory, or is `.vimrc` an exceptional file type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any file that is preceded by **`.`** is a hidden file.
`ls` will not show hidden files by default.

You can use the `-a`(all flag) to display ALL files.

```
$ ls -a
.
..
00001ea3_medium.jpeg
video.mp4
```

Using the  `-l` (long listing flag) will display more information regarding the files:

```
$ ls -al
-rw-rw-r--   1 za   za             7275 Apr  7 00:59  .xboardrc
-rwxr-xr-x   1 za   za              131 Apr 20  2017  .xinputrc
-rwxr-xr-x   1 za   za             8099 Apr 19  2017  .xscreensaver
-rw-------   1 za   za             3569 Jun 13 03:51  .xsession-errors
-rw-------   1 za   za             3569 Jun 12 22:28  .xsession-errors.old
```

You can read more about the `ls` command by reading the [manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) online or from terminal:

```
man ls
```

To filter the results you can use `grep` in combination with `ls`.

```
$ ls -al | grep vim
drwxr-xr-x   2 za   za             4096 May 15 02:53 .vim
-rwxr-xr-x   1 za   za            15049 May 25 21:51 .viminfo
```